# 2D ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a 2D ArrayList and I want to take one specific ArrayList from those that are inside the 2D ArrayList.

Is this possible? 
If yes how can I do this? 
How exactly does the 2D arrayList work, I have read a lot about it but I still can't understand.
My 2D ArrayList has this form:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Items>> arrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Items>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ArrayList<Items> row = new ArrayList<Items>();

    for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++)
    {
        // create the items...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need a new method of storing your information...

Comment: Arnold, if someone edits your post and improves it's quality, as a general rule, you should NOT roll back to the previous version of the post. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/FAQ) for more information on this topic.

Comment: ok Richard and i'm sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from the top:

`Is this possible?`

Yes, quite simple actually:

```
ArrayList innerList = arrayList.get(listIndex);
```

`How does the 2D ArrayList work?`

Basically, it functions as an array  of arrays, so that when you access one element of the 2D list, returns an ArrayList, which you must further call `get()` on to get the element you want.

Example:

```
ArrayList innerList = (ArrayList) arrayList.get(listIndex); // returns an arraylist
Item item = (Item) innerList.get(innerListIndex); // returns your item
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes this is possible.

Since you have an `ArrayList< ArrayList<Items> >` when you call `arrayList.get()` this will return an ArrayList. Then you can go ahead and do whatever you need.

For instance:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.length(); i++){
   ArrayList<Items> innerList = arrayList.get(i);
   for(int j =0; j < 10; j++){
       innerList.add(new Items());
   }
 }
```

This will take your ten ArrayLists you made above and fill each of them with ten items.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** this answer is for the original version of the question (which was a little difficult to understand).

If I understand you correctly, you want to flatten many lists into one.

```
List<List<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    List<String> thisList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    listOfLists.add(thisList);
}

// flatten
List<String> flattenedListOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
for (List<String> listOfString : listOfLists) {
    flattenedListOfStrings.addAll(listOfString);
}

// test
for (String string : flattenedListOfStrings) {
    System.out.print(string);
}
```

Outputs:

```
abcabcabcabcabc
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, you can pick ArrayList from an ArrayList. In order to do this you can follow these 2 steps:

> 1. Initialize and declare 2D ArrayList

As per your question, you have 10 rows (i = 10) and 500 columns (j=500).

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> row = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++)
        {
            //add any integers into "row" ArrayList
            row.add(2);
        }
        //add this above 1d "row" ArrayList to our 2D "arraylist" 
        arrayList.add(row);
    }
```

> 2. Fetch elements from an ArrayList

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayList.get(i).size(); j++) { 
            System.out.print(arrayList.get(i).get(j) + " "); 
        } 
        System.out.println(); 
    }
```